# suppress warning in DB2 9.7

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, db2, warnings

We are migrating our application to DB 9.7 from 9.1.
It seems when you store data from large size column to small size varible in stored proceduresin db2 9.1, it does not throw any warnings.

But DB2 9.7 throws.
In my application there are 400+ stored procedures and all are coded to treat warning as errors and control returns in case of any errors.

So when we migrated to new db2 9.7, my application is  stuck due to this as now many of our stored procedures are thorwing this warning :
`SQLCODE -445, warning: value has been truncated`

Now I want to suppress this warning so that I dont have to change the exiting functionality in existing stored procedures and which are so many in number.

So is there any way in DB2 to suppress these kind of specific or all warnings.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a warning, so it does not block your application. When I have this kind of message a do the following.

Let's suppose you have a 50-chars length column called name.

```
select varchar(name, 20)
from mytable;
```

With the previous query, I will truncate the column to 20 characters. However, if any value of the column has more that 20, your Warning message will appear.

To prevent that, I do a substring before the truncation:

```
select varchar(substr(name, 1, 20), 20)
from mytable;
```

With this, the output will be correct without any message. I you do the substr directly, you will have a smaller string, but the size of the output will the the original size.

Finally, you are dealing with stored procedures, thus, you can do two things:

- Modify the queries as I show you, to truncate the values with the right size
- Create a handler for warning with an empty body

For example:

```
DECLARE WARNING HANDLER FOR WARNING BEGIN END;
```

Comment: can u give me some more information about this handler, and how it works. Or any link will also help. We cannot change our queries as for this we have to manually find all the select queries in all of our stored procedures so this is not a good option for us. This handler option sounds good. Will this can resolve warning problem for a specific warning or it will stop all.

Comment: actually we have added code in all of our sps  to return in case of any errors/warning. In this case also will this handler work?

Comment: I suppose that when you execute a SP, you got that sql0445 form times to times. It means, that you have not "catched" that sqlstate, and it is returned to the caller. What you need is to make sure you deal with that http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0009028.html?lang=en

Answer (score -2):

Use the -o option. "o" stands for output and depending on your environment is set to default ON or OFF. You can check by doing "db2 LIST COMMAND OPTIONS".  If "-o" is set to "ON" (like mine) you'll use "+o" to turn if off. Or use "-o" if your default is set to "OFF".

So, your command if you were terminating your connection and would not like to see the message stating that you have indeed terminated your connection would look like this if it were on my box:

db2 +o terminate;

Or you may need:

db2 -o terminate;

Since it's real super easy to just change "+" to "-" and vice-versa, don't both with looking up your defaults, just use the "o" option with the plus or minus until your messages no longer appear.